# Asus MemoPad ME302KL reboots when playing youtube videos

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

I've bought recently a Asus MemoPad ME302KL. It is very nice and work well on skype videocalls and everything else excepto to see videos. When i'm going to see a youtube video or a facebook video, it reboots itself and after the reboot it plays the video very well.
Most of times that I'm going to see a video, I'm in a skype videocall but after the reboot it works, soo it's probably a software problem.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The problem is solved. Seems to be a problem with de graphis of the equipment. It was changed by warranty.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, please post an answer explaining what was wrong, so that other visitors can see that your question is answered.

Comment: I've gone to the store where i've bought the pad and they change for other so that the one with the problems can go to the de Asus Support for changing the graphics chipset.

Comment: Good, so click **Answer your question** below, add that as an *answer*, and then accept it as the right answer. *Comments* are just for clarification. Right now your question still shows up as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone to the store where i've bought the pad and they change for other so that the one with the problems can go to the de Asus Support for changing the graphics chipset.